# Apache mapping URL to CGI script

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi

In Apache I would like a URL "/myscript" or "/myscript?param=myparam" to execute a CGI script located at:

```
/usr/local/scripts/custom.pl
```

I have tried:

```
Action custom-action /usr/local/scripts/custom.pl
<Location "/myscript">
    SetHandler custom-action
</Location>
```

but this isn't working.

Any ideas how I can achieve the mapping of URL to script?

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite can easily do that with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myscript$
RewriteRules (.*) /usr/local/scripts/custom.pl
```

Be sure to set permissions appropriately, both the actual file permissions and a Directory Directive to allow access to that folder.

Example Directory Directive:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/scripts">
    Allow from All
    AllowOverride None
    Options None +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your handler will work if you create a file or directory in DOCUMENT_ROOT called myscript.  Haven't worked out why yet, but it works!

[edit] Seems that if you're using Action to define the handler then you're effectively creating a filter through which the files in the filesystem will be passed (e.g. for DIY server-side include processing).  If the target doesn't exist in the filesystem then there's nothing to pass to your script (through PATH_TRANSLATED) so the server throws an error.